# Fastest way to search an array for matches in another array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, search

Background I have two or greater files that I need to search through for matches. These files can easily have more than 20,000 lines. I need to find the fastest way to search through them and find matches between files.

I've never done matching like this, where there could me more than one match and I need to return them all.

What I know:

- A file cannot match with itself.
- Files match based on a set of fields. If any of the fields match, the
  row matches.
- This will be run fairly frequently so it needs to be as fast as possilbe.

My current method involves excessive use of the IEnumerable LINQ methods.

```
    Dim fileNames As String() = lstFiles.Items.OfType(Of String)().ToArray()
    Dim fileText As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of CCDDetail)) = fileNames.Select(Function(fileName, fileIndex)
                                                                                     Dim list As New List(Of String)({fileName})
                                                                                     list.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(fileName))
                                                                                     Return list.Where(Function(fileLine, lineIndex) Not {list.Count - 1, list.Count - 2, 0, 1, 2}.Contains(lineIndex)).
                                                                                         Select(Function(fileLine) New CCDDetail(list(0), fileLine.Substring(12, 17).Trim(), fileLine.Substring(29, 10).Trim(), fileLine.Substring(39, 8).Trim(), fileLine.Substring(48, 6).Trim(), fileLine.Substring(54, 22).Trim()))
                                                                                 End Function)
    Dim asdf = fileText.
        Select(Function(file, inx) file.
                        Select(Function(fileLine, ix) fileText.
                                   Skip(inx + 1).
                                   Select(Function(fileToSearch) fileLine.MatchesAny(ix, fileToSearch)).
                                   Aggregate(New List(Of Integer)(), Function(old, cc)
                                                                         Dim lcc As New List(Of Integer)(cc)
                                                                         lcc.Insert(0, If(old.Count > 0, old(0) + 1, 1))
                                                                         old.AddRange(lcc)
                                                                         Return old
                                                                     End Function)))
```

Functions in CCDDetail:

```
Public Function Matches(ccd2 As CCDDetail) As Boolean
    Return CustomerName = ccd2.CustomerName OrElse
            DfiAccountNumber = ccd2.DfiAccountNumber OrElse
            CustomerRefId = ccd2.CustomerRefId OrElse
            PaymentAmount = ccd2.PaymentAmount OrElse
            PaymentId = ccd2.PaymentId
End Function

Public Function MatchesAny(index As Integer, ccd2 As IEnumerable(Of CCDDetail)) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Return Enumerable.Range(0, ccd2.Count).Where(Function(i) ccd2(i).Matches(Me))
End Function
```

This works on my test files, however when using full length files it takes around seven minutes.

Questions:

- Does LINQ slow things down too much? Should I write my own loops?
- Should I use regex rather than Substring?

Is there a faster way of doing this? Any performance tips?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I just got it down to quite a lot less using a list of dictionaries and regex. I'll finish the application and then do some tests comparing variations.

```
    Dim fileNames As String() = lstFiles.Items.OfType(Of String)().ToArray()
    Dim textFiles As New List(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, CCDDetail))()
    Dim fileInnerText As String()
    Dim reg As Regex = New Regex(".{12}(.{17})(.{10})(.{8}).(.{6})(.{22})", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    Dim mat As Match
    Dim fileSpecText As Dictionary(Of Integer, CCDDetail)
    Dim lineMatches As New List(Of Integer())
    For i As Integer = 0 To fileNames.Length - 1
        fileInnerText = File.ReadAllLines(fileNames(i))
        fileSpecText = New Dictionary(Of Integer, CCDDetail)()
        For j As Integer = 2 To fileInnerText.Length - 3
            mat = reg.Match(fileInnerText(j))
            fileSpecText.Add(j, New CCDDetail(mat.Groups(1).Value, mat.Groups(2).Value, mat.Groups(3).Value, mat.Groups(4).Value, mat.Groups(5).Value))
        Next
        textFiles.Add(fileSpecText)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To textFiles.Count - 1
        'Dim source As Dictionary(Of Integer, CCDDetail) = textFiles(i)
        For j As Integer = 2 To textFiles(i).Count - 1 + 2
            For k As Integer = i + 1 To textFiles.Count - 1
                For l As Integer = 2 To textFiles(k).Count - 1 + 2
                    If (textFiles(i)(j).Matches(textFiles(k)(l))) Then
                        lineMatches.Add({i, j, k, l})
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: 1. Sort `O(N logN)` 2. Iterate through both comparing the top elements `O(N)`. On (mis)match just move the cursor further down

Comment: First 2 questions can't be answered on SO (whether code is fast enough for you or not can be answered only by you)... Last one - I'd expected some sort of `Intersect` but if your code works for you not sure if I'd change it.

Comment: @zerkms should not it be O(N)  (dictionary for both and iterate to find matches)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov those are arrays - you just compare the elements one by one, without any lookups. So it's exactly linear with `N` to be proportional the longest array. Ex: `1, 4, 5`, `1, 2, 5`. `1-1` match, `4 - 2` no, `4 - 5` - no, `5-5` yes.

Comment: @zerkms but with Dictionary you don't pay price for sorting...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I see. Yes, that would work as well.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not asking if it's fast enough, I'm simply asking if it can be made faster. Would Intersect be faster than what I'm currently doing? I think I could override .Equals. However, I need to keep track of every match to display it later, so I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: So if I use a dictionary what should I use for the key? I haven't used dictionaries very much.

Comment: Well, you actually could use a `HashSet`, not a `Dictionary`

Comment: @FelesMortis "slow things down *too much*" - LINQ queries are slower than equivalent direct loops, you would have to try both and measure for *your particular case*... same for regex. Use profiler or just `Stopwatch` class to measure each piece and decide - for some even 1% would be too much, others 2x does not matter.

Comment: @FelesMortis  `Dictionary`/`HashSet` are very important data structures and I'd recommend you to learn them. In your case key would be set of all fields that you use in your  `Matches` on (custom comparer is generally more expressive than defining strange-looking equals that compares just half of the fields). Depending on whether items unique or not you may need to keep list of items for each key. You may also want to keep addition information on where item come from (file/line) if it is important.

Comment: Could you clarify matching?  When you compare 2 files, are you comparing line 1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc?  Or are you searching the second file for any line that matches first file line 1, and then any line that matches first file line 2, etc.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to match one line to many lines.

Comment: also, For j As Integer = 2 To textFiles(i).Count - 1 + 2
you already skipped and ignored the lines when you initialized the dictionary (and I think you mean ...Count - (1+2), rather than ...Count -1 + 2  )

Comment: also, the way you use the dictionary defeats the purpose of using the dictionary, you are not utilizing the power of the hash lookup

Comment: @Les I'm matching one line to each line in all other files. For every line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @GertArnold [Vote to close because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, not because it belongs somewhere else](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286591/1310566). Voting to close because it belongs somewhere else can cause situations where the question is closed on two places. It is okay to redirect people to other sites, but don't vote to close with that reason.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Voting to close because the question belongs somewhere else is one of the off-topic close reasons. The only thing is, there is no migration path to CR because the site is still in beta.

Comment: @GertArnold [CR has officially graduated](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/code-review-se-is-graduating), but waiting for a new design and stuff. Even after CR graduates, with the number of bad suggestions to post there, [it is still not certain it will be a migration target](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1310566). [And about voting to close as off-topic...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287401/1310566)

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry if this is off-topic. I agree that it would be better on Code Review, I just didn't know that Code Review existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please view my comments to your question.  The following (untested) example code shows how you could use the Dictionary<> to possibly speed things up.  It takes your "Update" and builds from there so that you can follow my C# example (sorry, I don't write VB.net).  The idea is that it is faster to use your field as a key to find all matching lines (lines that have the same field value).

Your code (and mine) could be further improved to not load all files into memory at once, and when comparing two files, you only need one loaded into the dictionary at a time.

```
    public void CompareLines(string[] fileNames)
    {
        var textFileDictionaries = new List<Dictionary<CCDDetail,List<int>>>();
        var reg  = new Regex(".{12}(.{17})(.{10})(.{8}).(.{6})(.{22})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var lineMatches = new List<LineMatch>();

        foreach(var f in fileNames)
        {
            var fileInnerText = File.ReadAllLines(f);
            var fileSpecText = new Dictionary<CCDDetail,List<int>>();
            for(int j = 1; j < fileInnerText.Length - 4; ++j) // ignore 1st and last 4 lines of file
            {
                var mat = reg.Match(fileInnerText[j]);
                for(int k=1; k<=5; ++k)
                {
                    var key = new CCDDetail() { FieldId = k, Value = mat.Groups[k].Value };
                    //field and value may occur on multiple lines?
                    if (fileSpecText.ContainsKey(key) == false)
                        fileSpecText.Add(key, new List<int>());
                    fileSpecText[key].Add(j);
                }
            }
            textFileDictionaries.Add(fileSpecText);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<textFileDictionaries.Count - 2; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < textFileDictionaries.Count - 1; ++j)
            {
                foreach(var tup in textFileDictionaries[j])
                {
                    if(textFileDictionaries[i].ContainsKey(tup.Key))
                    {
                        // the field value might occure on multiple lines
                        lineMatches.Add(new LineMatch() { 
                            File1Index=i,
                            File1Lines = textFileDictionaries[i][tup.Key],
                            File2Index=j,
                            File2Lines = textFileDictionaries[j][tup.Key]
                        });
                    }
                }
                /*
                for (int k = 0; k < textFileDictionaries[j].Count; ++k)
                {
                    var key = textFileDictionaries[j].Keys.ToArray()[k];
                    if (textFileDictionaries[i].ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        // the field value might occure on multiple lines
                        lineMatches.Add(new LineMatch()
                        {
                            File1Index = i,
                            File1Lines = textFileDictionaries[i][key],
                            File2Index = j,
                            File2Lines = textFileDictionaries[j][key]
                        });
                    }
                }
               */
            }
        }
    }

....

public class CCDDetail
{
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return FieldId == (obj as CCDDetail).FieldId && Value.Equals((obj as CCDDetail).Value);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return FieldId.GetHashCode() + Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
public class LineMatch
{
    public int File1Index { get; set; }
    public List<int> File1Lines { get; set; }
    public int File2Index { get; set; }
    public List<int> File2Lines { get; set; }
}
```

Keep in mind, my assumption is you can have the same field value on multiple lines in either file being compared.  Also, the LineMatch list needs post processing because it contains records of all the lines of both files that have a field in common (you might want to record which field number.

Comment: First, I actually prefer C#, I'm just forced to use VB for work. The trouble is that I need to track matches based on 5 fields in each line. If any field matches, it's a match. If more fields match, then it's a stronger match. I can probably change the order of the last few loops.

Comment: Another thought. Do you know if `foreach` is faster for dictionaries than `for`? I tend to stay away from `foreach` in situations where I value performance.

Comment: If you prefer for instead of foreach, see my updated code comments.  Also, I am still unsure if you can have the same field value show up on multiple lines in either file.  If so, what do you want to report?

Comment: One line in a file has several fields. I need to find all line matches, what they matched, and the strength of the match(how many fields in that line matched the destination line). I do not need to track matches in the same file. I also need to track the total matches, and the matches on each field. I also need to track then number of matches of each strength.

Comment: Your method is roughly 10000 times faster than mine. I've still got to find the difference in post-processing time, as my code outputs in a format that makes it easier to use.